# Does anyone know how to map GTFS data info into http://simcity.vasile.ch/sbb/?

Tags: php, json, google-maps-api-3, gtfs

Need your suggestions , in order to go with a script that is already working using google map & json files?
Or Do i use any other open source code to show live train simulator using GTFS Data.

My aim is to create a running simulator somthing like:
https://github.com/vasile/vehicle-simulator

Help me in creating the files that were used in https://github.com/vasile/vehicle-simulator this simulator?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Aim is simple i am using the code  https://github.com/vasile/vehicle-simulator from here and want the Github Simulator to show GTFS data. Please help me out in this regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added support for GTFS :)

Check https://github.com/vasile/GTFS-viz

Comment: Thanks but i have few questions, why the tool is create a SQLITE database? since we only need Geo Json , KML files to show the data on your mapp!!